parse json object and get original substring
Given the JSON below, I currently have Jackson code that will parse it into an object with an array of sub-objects.  I can serialize each of the sub-objects back into a String easily enough.
But I'm finding lots of corner cases where the output string is not exactly the input string.  For instance, output field ordering doesn't necessarily match input field ordering.  The corner case that got me started on this is that I noticed that if my sub-objects declare the "URL" field as a URL, then "" translates to null, not "", and is thus output as null.
So my question is, is there a way to get Jackson to break a string up into substrings representing the sub-objects, rather than parsing it into actual Java objects?
{
  "foo": "bar",
  "baz": [
    {
      "index": 1,
      "url": ""
    },
    {
      "url": "https://example.com",
      "index": 2
    }
  ]
}

Said another way, in the case above, what I want is a List<String> with 2 elements:
    {
      "index": 1,
      "url": ""
    }

and
    {
      "url": "https://example.com",
      "index": 2
    }

Am I crazy?  Would I have to write a custom deserializer?  I feel like Jackson has to more or less do this already, I just need a way to get at it.
Thank you very much.

Edited to add code.
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("foo")
    @Builder @Value @Jacksonized
    public static class Wrapper {
        List<SubObject> baz;
    }

    @Builder @Value @Jacksonized
    public static class SubObject {
        Integer index;
        URL url;
    }

    @Test
    public void runTest() throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper().registerModule(new VavrModule());    //for the Vavr List
        Wrapper wrapper = om.readValue(new File("src/test/resources/fixtures/WrapperFile.json"), Wrapper.class);
        List<SubObject> subObjects = wrapper.baz;
        List<String> subObjectStrings = subObjects.map(so -> safeWriteValueAsString(om, so));
        subObjectStrings.forEach(s -> System.out.println(s));
    }

yields this output
{"index":1,"url":null}
{"index":2,"url":"https://example.com"}

Note that neither of these is what I want.
The second subobject string is in the wrong order.
The first subobject has an URL of null rather than "".  While I can handle the URL issue by making it a String rather than a URL, that's one possible case, not the general case.
What I'd like is something like what's below (note that it doesn't compile.  This is what I'm looking for, not what I have).  I know that jackson has to be able to read the string and decide when a SubObject has started and ended.  It should be possible to get the substrings, and/or the indices.  If I have the strings that represent each of the objects in the array, I can easily use Jackson to parse them into actual SubObjects if I need to.
    // my theory of how it _could_ work
    @Test
    public void theoryTest() {
        ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper().registerModule(new VavrModule());  //for the Vavr List
        Map<String, String> propertyStrings = om.parseIntoPropertyStrings(f);
        String bazString = propertyStrings.getOrElse("baz", "");
        List<String> bazEntryStrings = om.parseIntoArray(bazString);
        bazEntryStrings.forEach(s -> System.out.println(s);)
    }


It's not really clear what you are asking. You should add the classes and the code you are using for (de)serialization. I also believe you have two separate problems that may be better in put into two questions. One thing, if I understand you correctly: The order of properties in JSON objects are not defined. For all intents and purposes {"A": 1, "B": 2} and {"B": 2, "A": 1} are the same, and JSON parsers won't usually retain the order, so a custom deserializer won't help you. Also it would be dangerous to rely on it. If the order is import, you must use an array: [{'A': 1}, {"B": 2}].

Ok, I got what I was aiming for (below), which was to get the ObjectMapper to parse my JSON into the sub-objects I cared about, but then give me the raw string for that sub-object's JSON.  The magic is that in the SubObjectDeserializer you do p.getCodec().readTree(p).toString();.  That way you have the original string, which is what I wanted, and if you want, you can also deserialize it "normally".
The lombok annotations are just a boilerplate remover, it doesn't change anything about the question I was working out.
The code
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonDeserialize;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer;

import io.vavr.collection.List;
import io.vavr.collection.Map;
import io.vavr.jackson.datatype.VavrModule;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.SneakyThrows;
import lombok.Value;
import lombok.extern.jackson.Jacksonized;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

@Slf4j
public class WrapperSubObjectTest {

    File f = new File("src/test/resources/fixtures/WrapperFile.json");

    @Builder @Value @Jacksonized @JsonIgnoreProperties("foo")
    public static class Wrapper {
        List<SubObject> baz;
    }

    @Builder @Value @JsonDeserialize(using = SubObjectDeserializer.class)
    public static class SubObject {
        Integer index;
        String url;
        String originalString;
    }

    private static final ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper().registerModule(new VavrModule());

    public static class SubObjectDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<SubObject> {
        public SubObjectDeserializer() { this(SubObject.class); } 
        public SubObjectDeserializer(Class<?> vc) { super(vc); }

        @Override
        public SubObject deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt)
                throws IOException, JsonProcessingException
        {
            String s = p.getCodec().readTree(p).toString();
            TypeReference<Map<String, String>> mapTR = new TypeReference<Map<String, String>>() {};
            Map<String, String> map = om.readValue(s, mapTR);

            SubObject returnVal = new SubObject(Integer.parseInt(map.get("index").getOrElse("-1"))
                    , map.get("url").getOrElse("https://badvalue.com"), s);
            return returnVal;
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void runTest() throws IOException {
        log.info("contents of file \n{}\n\nParsing results", Files.readString(f.toPath()));
        Wrapper wrapper = om.readValue(f, Wrapper.class);
        List<SubObject> subObjects = wrapper.baz;
        subObjects.forEach(so -> safeWriteValueAsString(om, so));
    }


    @SneakyThrows
    private void safeWriteValueAsString(ObjectMapper om, SubObject so) {
        log.info("\noriginalString = {}\nparsed = {}", so.originalString, om.writeValueAsString(so));
    }
}


The output
contents of file 
{
  "foo": "bar",
  "baz": [
    {
      "index": 1,
      "url": ""
    },
    {
      "url": "https://example.com",
      "index": 2
    }
  ]
}

Parsing results
originalString = {"index":1,"url":""}
parsed = {"index":1,"url":"","originalString":"{\"index\":1,\"url\":\"\"}"}
originalString = {"url":"https://example.com","index":2}
parsed = {"index":2,"url":"https://example.com","originalString":"{\"url\":\"https://example.com\",\"index\":2}"}

